# why is the "app" folder missing from my android studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to the android studio. I made a new project, with these options:
1- language= java
2- for phone or tablets
3- empty activity / no activity
but the folders in my project are completely different from everyone else. 
[image]
[image: you can see it in the attached image].
why is this happening to my project? why I don't have Java, manifest, build.gradle (module:app) and ... folders in my project?

Comment: Java, manifest, build.gradle (module:app) inside the app folder

Comment: it is not. i have edited my question, now you can see inside the app folder too

Comment: It is available inside you app folder as you can see *build.gradle* file is app build gradle

Comment: build.gradle (module:app) is inside the app folder, and manifest and java folder at app > src > main path

Answer (score 0):

In project section may you left side **android icon** and

right side **setting icon**

do:-
  click on **setting icon** ,hence you can see **Compact middle package**, select this.

Comment: the compact middle package was selected, so i deselected it and select it again, nothing happened.

Comment: you select  app->src

Comment: if not found. inside src you can see you package or folder ,Continue click

Answer (score 0):

your gradle is not build successfully.
rebuild project. see gradle problem, and fix it for solve project structure.

Comment: I think that can cause the problem, because I get an error which tells me that it can not sync the gradle

Comment: it says it can not download gradle-5.4.1-all.zip. is it because of my internet? what should I do? I even changed my region

Comment: yes problem is internet connection. try to fix it for download gradle version.

Comment: thanks a lot, I'm doing as you said, let's see what happens

Comment: why my gradle icon is a grey elephant and others gradle icon are  a green circle? does it have anything to do with my problem?

Comment: i like your question :)). your icon is grey elephant like me. because you have new version of android studio and green circle was for old version. no problem for this.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me recently. Files existed. Only visible under the Project...Project tab.
I prefer the Project... Android... tab
It was only showing the "Gradle Scripts" and missing the "app" folder.

App Missing in Android Tab of Android Studio

1. In Android Studio "Welcome" dialog, remove project from recent list
2. Close everything Explorer Navigate to folder
   C:\Users\Andy\AndroidStudioProjects[project]\
3. Search *.iml
4. Delete these files (backup beforehand as always)
5. Open Android Studio as Administrator
6. Open Project with “Open” button and browse to file folder
7. Android tab… “app” should appear now.

[image: App folder restored]